# Make a landscape table in a word document

Tags: r, reporters

I am using `ReporteRs` package in R to create a report. I have a table which has 13 columns and I would like it to go in a landscape orientation. Otherwise some columns will be cut down from the table. I am wondering whether it is possible to specify this in ReporteRs for a specific FlexTable object? All the other tables and texts come in portrait format. My apologies for not giving a reproducible example. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `addSection`:

```
library(ReporteRs)
doc = docx()
doc = addSection( doc, landscape = T ) 
doc = addFlexTable( doc, FlexTable( mtcars) )
doc = addSection( doc, landscape = F ) 
writeDoc( doc, "test.docx")
```

Another solution would be to create an empty Word document with landscape orientation and then to use it as a template:

```
library(ReporteRs)
doc = docx(template = "your_landscape_doc.docx")
doc = addFlexTable( doc, FlexTable( mtcars) )
writeDoc( doc, "test.docx")
```

Comment: The closing `addSection()` call is important and landscape doesn't work for me otherwise.